# How to count occurence of a string in csv file

Tags: csv, unix, text, awk, sed

I've CSV file

```
author,host,authority,contents
_angelsuman,http://twitter.com/_angelsuman,5,green tea piyo :( #kicktraileron6thjune
_angelsuman,http://twitter.com/_angelsuman,5,rt @121training fat burning foods: grapefruit  watermelon  berries  hot peppers  celery  greek yogurt  eggs  fish  green tea  coffee  water  oatmeal.
_angelsuman,http://twitter.com/_angelsuman,5,rt @121training fat burning foods: â´ grapefruit â´ watermelon â´ berries â´ hot peppers â´ celery â´ greek yogurt â´ eggs â´ fish â´ green tea â´ oatmeal
anukshp,http://twitter.com/anukshp,4,rt @_angelsuman dear green tea u suck..:/ but i need to sip uh for myh rsn :( zindagi ka kdwa such :/ :(
```

I want to identify count of occurrences of first column :"author" in fourth column "contents"

Ex: finding "_angelsuman" in contents.

Kindly suggest; how can i achieve same?

Comment: Can "contents" contain commas?

Comment: For now ; we can assume NO. Content does not contain commas

Comment: I don't see any "author" in the fourth field.  Are you sure you worded your question correctly.  Are you looking for any of the first column values in the fourth column?

Comment: Yes; I'm looking for first column value in fourth column (anywhere in the string).

Answer (score 1):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
use Text::CSV;

my $col = 4; // 4th column

my $count = 0;
my @rows;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } )  # should set binary attribute.
    or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();

open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", "/tmp/test.csv" or die "test.csv: $!";
while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) {
    if ($row->[$col -1] eq 'author') {
        $count++;
    }
}
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();
close $fh;
print "There's $count occurences of 'author'\n";
```

#### Output :

```
There's 1 occurences of 'author'
```

#### Note :

This is a proper parsing with a perl module.

Replace `/tmp/test.csv` by your own file

Comment: I'm trying to find occurance of first column in fourth column.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows (assume that there is no comma in values as you said).

**one-line:**

`awk -F, 'NR>1 {author[$1]=0; content[NR]=$4} END {for (a in author) {for (c in content) {count[a]+=gsub(a,"",content[c])} print a, count[a]}}' file`

**expanded:**

```
awk -F, '
    NR>1 {
        author[$1]=0;
        content[NR]=$4
    }
    END {
        for (a in author) {
          for (c in content) {
              count[a] += gsub(a,"",content[c])
          }
          print a, count[a]
        }
    }' file
```

**How it works**

- read file with a comma separator `-F,` and skip the first line `NR>1`

  `awk -F, 'NR>1`
- store the first column in array `author` as the key - so every unique value will be stored once. Store the content in array `content` with the key equal of line number `NR` - this results of storing content from every line.

  ```
  {
  author[$1]=0;
  content[NR]=$4
  }
  ```
- at the end iterate by every unique author `for (a in author)` and foreach author iterate by content `for (c in content)` and increase number of occurences of author in content for specific author `count[a]+=gsub(a,"",content[c])`.
  If it is counted for specific `author`, then print results `print a, count[a]`.

  ```
  END {
      for (a in author) {
        for (c in content) {
          count[a]+=gsub(a,"",content[c])
        }
        print a, count[a]
      }
  }' file
  ```

**Output**

```
_angelsuman 1
anukshp 0
```

Comment: for _angelsuman count is accepted as 1 ; because it's appearing in line 4. Column 1 value can be anywhere in column 4

Comment: ok, understand, I've improved answer to these requirements, check it please